# How do I gain enough knowledge to experiment with cryptography?

Tags: education

There seems to be a common trend among forums involving the topic of cryptography to shutdown any conversation very quickly, least in my experience.

From the stand point of a newcomer to the field making bold claims and selling snake oil I can understand the trepidation and warnings. But as someone who has been reading the books, studying the courses, and experimenting with code when do they graduate to being able to ask educated questions and get more discourse beyond “thou shall not write your own stuff?”

For example. I know enough to not write my own cipher. I use battle tested technology like AES-GCM. But what if my experiment wishes to use it in a different way. Maybe a communication protocol for a learning exercise? Or chunking algorithm that uses the cipher for larger payloads?

When addressing these application level ideas I find it very hard to get any dialogue or information because I’m not allowed to do it myself even if the system I’m targeting lacks something.

My deepest apologies if this is off topic to this SE. I’m just at a loss on how to find educational discourse about cryptography and its use without the gate keeping that happens in this community.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "experiment with cryptography". If you mean this *in production* then there's a uniformly negative view of the topic. For experimenting with cryptography for fun, not all cryptographers view this negatively (see for example [this podcast](https://securitycryptographywhatever.com/2021/07/31/the-great-roll-your-own-crypto-debate-with-filippo-valsorda/)).

Comment: If you wanna try an existing and open source communication protocol that will blow your mind, check out [The X3DH Key Agreement Protocol](https://www.signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/). If encryption went to the gym 7 days a week and used steroids, this would be it. End-2-End-Encryption that uses nothing possibly created by the NSA.

Comment: @suchislife: "uses nothing possibly created by the NSA"; actually SHA-256 and SHA-512 **was** designed by the NSA :-)

Comment: Damn it poncho, you got me there. As far as encryption, No.

Comment: Does anyone feel this is good as a meta discussion?

Comment: @MarkSchultz-Wu I would presume that for _in production_ I’d require auditing/vetting. The original intent of the question was in response to a principle shooting me down with “never make your own” to what I thought was a curiosity question: “In WebCrypto, which does not support streaming, can I support streaming by encrypting each chunk instead of the whole buffer?” As an example this kind of exchange happens and the discussion never actually happens; hence this question.

Comment: The first comment to you from @MarkSchultz-Wu is his view only.  There are many here that believe a mono-culture approach to encryption is both foolish & dangerous.  "Eggs in one basket?"  Just ask an Irish potato farmer or any bacterium. Look though the questions here to prove that to yourself, especially regarding various one time pad implementations.

Comment: nothing wrong with the question as asked, I think. It can be answered either here or in meta.

Comment: @PaulUszak I've tried asking a bacterium, but it is tricky to get them answering. If you can reference a particular one by name I'm all ears.